# GPS Navigation for webservice android

Tags: android

How to show in app navigation for finding direction and searching any place? It happens when we open google map in browser.But i want the same in app.

Comment: Check this question and answers: [Google maps android: How do I add driving or walking directions to a specific geopoint with a button onclick?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619972/google-maps-android-how-do-i-add-driving-or-walking-directions-to-a-specific-ge/12716403#12716403)